# Passing array as a parameter

Tags: c++

I read in a book that, `int f (int P[2][4])` cannot accept `A[2][3]`, but `B[3][4]` is fine. what is the reason for this?
Especially when we create dynamic allocation using pointers, this should not be a problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that function parameters never really have array type.  The compiler treats the declaration

```
int f(int P[2][4]);
```

as though it really said

```
int f(int (*P)[4]);
```

`P` is a pointer to an array of four `int`s.  The type `int [3][4]` decays to that same type.  But the type `int [2][3]` decays to the type `int (*)[3]` instead, which is not compatible.

Dynamic allocation is another matter entirely, and it probably does *not* involve array-of-array types no matter how you do it.  (Array of pointers, more likely.)

Comment: @Ben Then the parameter type would be reference-to-array-of-arrays.  That's not an array type in the same way that reference-to-class-type is not a class type.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm just mentioning another case that is so similar as to be worth mentioning (IMO).

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that
    int f( int P[2][4] );
is a synonym for
    int f( int (*P)[4] );
The first dimension in a function declaration is just comments.

Comment: +1. There's a surprising exception for variadic functions though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353407/var-args-last-named-parameter-not-function-or-array :)

Comment: @Frustrated Coder: No he is not from IITB. He is `litb` (let-it-be) :)

Great to see James Kanze answering on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not allowed, because `f(int P[2][4])` becomes `f(int (*P)[4])` so you can pass `int B[3][4]` which can decay into `int (*B)[4]`, but `int A[2][3]` **cannot** decay into `int (*A)[4]`, so the latter will not be accepted by `f(int (*P)[4])`.

The type `int (*)[3]` is incompatible with `int (*)[4]`. One cannot convert to the other!

However there is a solution. You can do this:

```
 template<size_t M, size_t N>
 int f(int (&P)[M][N])
 {
      //Use M and N as dimensions of the 2D array!
 }

 //Usage
 int A[2][3];
 f(A); //M becomes 2, N becomes 3

 int  B[3][4];
 f(B); //M becomes 3, N becomes 4
```

It will accept all two dimensional arrays!

Comment: Question was "why not possible?", not "how to avoid?"

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, if you specify a function takes 2-D arrays, then it has to be given an explicit column size (the second `[]`). The row size (first `[]`) is optional.

Answer (score 1):

It has todo with the memory layout. The first number is basically your number of rows and the second is how many elements are in each row. Rows are placed directly after each other. So there offset is determined by the number of elements in the rows multiplied by the number of rows preceding. The compiled function will be calculating row offsets based on 4 elements. When you pass an array with another row length these calculations will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter define the 2d array type since it's differs how many elements will be in every column.

The first parameter is only define the size of the array, and since you can send longer array to that function, it's like passing parameter with type: int*[3] which is similar to passing 1d array with size 10 to function that expect to get array with shorter size - and this is legal in c++.